# Where to put compiled JS in NodeJS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory-structure, uglifyjs

I am building a NodeJS application and I am not sure where I should compile my Javascript to (i.e. minified and uglified Javascript) and how to structure my app.

All the examples I have found online say to simply make a `/public` directory and put all the JS in there.

The problem with that is that even if I serve the Javascript file `app.min.js` from `/public/js`, it is still really easy for someone to figure out that at `public/js/app.js` he can find all my original javascript code and steal it.

What is the proper way to structure the app so I can separate development files and distribution files?

Answer (score 0):

You put your public JS files in a directory that your node.js server serves up to the public and you put your private source files somewhere else that your node.js server does NOT give any access to the public.

Simply don't put private files that you don't intend to share anywhere in the same hierarchy as your public files that your node.js has routes configured to serve.

Remember, your node.js server ONLY serves files or directories that you have explicit routes for.  So, just make sure the private files are somewhere other than those directories containing publicly served files.

---

There are lots of different ways to structure it (and none is any more "right" than any other as it depends upon what else you have in your file structure).   For a simple system, I create a specific "public" directory below my server and I put all public stuff off of that.  I can then use `express.static()` routes for the public hierarchy and nothing private ever gets shared.

Comment: but if my development files are in the non public folder, when I develop I have to compile them each time into the public folder to test them. This is a bit of a pain even eith Grunt watch

Comment: @CodyBugstein - Yeah, that's the cost of separating your public and private files.  If your html files reference the `xxx.min.js` file, you always have to compile after a change anyway.  You could have a scheme for development/testing where the public and private files were co-located and a build script for deployment that copies only the public files to your public server.